# Every bounded function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

When we say "Every bounded function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$", then does it mean that $[a,b]$ is the domain of the function or any closed interval? I think that it is true considering the fact that $[a,b]$ is the domain of $f$. But upon discussion, it turns out to be false when we consider Dirichlet function:

$$
\begin{cases}
1,\quad x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
0,\quad x \in \mathbb{Q}^{c}
\end{cases}
$$

This function is not Riemann integrable on any closed interval. Thus, this function would be a counter-example for the above statement.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The statement that "every bounded function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable" is false, and the Dirichlet function is the standard cunterexample.

Comment: I'm not sure who "we" is, but anybody who says "Every bounded function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$" is wrong, as your counterexample shows.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are asking if something is true or not but you just told us a counterexample. Do you not believe your own example?

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger I wanted to ask if the interval [a,b] in the above question is the domain of f or just any closed interval different from the domain of f? Because if the domain of f is [a,b], then the above statement should be true.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal the domain can be any non-degenerated closed interval and it remains false. If $f$ is defined on the interval $[a,b]$ you can modify your function to be $a$ on $[a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $b$ on $[a,b] \cap (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})$. Actually, you can make any choice to the pair $\{0,1\}$ of different numbers in the codomain and the counterexample still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reiterate multiple comments, the statement "Every bounded function on $[a, b]$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a, b]$" is false.

In response to the clarification, "I wanted to ask if the interval $[a, b]$ in the above question is the domain of $f$ or just any closed interval different from the domain of $f$?":

If we say "$f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$" we're implicitly assuming the domain of $f$ *contains* $[a, b]$ (in practice), or that the domain of $f$ *is* $[a, b]$ (being pedantically literal about the definition).

In practice, being loose about this issue doesn't matter. If $f$ is defined on some closed, bounded real interval $I$, and if $[a, b] \subseteq I$, then in saying, "$f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$" we can replace $f$ by either

1. The restriction $f|_{[a,b]}$ of $f$ to $[a, b]$, i.e., the function whose domain is $[a, b]$ and whose values agree with the values of $f$ on $[a, b]$. In symbols, $f|_{[a,b]}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$.
2. The product of $f$ and the indicator function $\chi_{[a,b]}$ of $[a, b]$, i.e., the function whose domain is $I$ and whose values agree with the values of $f$ on $[a, b]$ and are $0$ off $[a, b]$. In symbols,
   $$
   (f \cdot \chi_{[a,b]})(x)
   = \begin{cases}
     f(x) & x \in [a, b], \\
     0 & x \not\in [a, b].
   \end{cases}
   $$

The choice doesn't matter because if $f$ is integrable on $I$, then:

1. The restriction of $f$ to $[a, b]$ is integrable on $[a, b]$,
2. The product of $f$ with the indicator function of $[a, b]$ is integrable on $I$, and
3. The integral of the product over $I$ is the integral of the restriction over $[a, b]$:
   $$
   \int_{I} f \cdot \chi_{[a,b]} = \int_{a}^{b} f|_{[a,b]}.
   $$

Answer (score 1):

A bounded function is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if the set of points at which it is not continuous has measure zero. This is Lebesgue's theorem. The Dirichlet function is nowhere continuous.

Comment: When you say "on [a,b]", does that mean the domain of f or any closed interval?

Comment: Any closed interval in the domain of $f$? Or that the domain is being taken to be this closed interval.

Comment: Any closed interval within the domain or the entirety of domain if the domain is bounded. For unbounded domains, it becomes an improper integral and we need to be more careful.